# Smalltalk's ReadWrite stream "atEND" evaluation has no effect

Tags: stream, udp, smalltalk, visualworks

I'm evaluating the following block :

```
[byteStream atEnd] whileFalse: [stream nextPut: self parsePacket]
```

The problem is that my " byteStream" which is a ReadWrite stream, is at its end, (I inspect it and the position = the read limit = the write limit = 512) and my loop does not stop, like if the : " [byteStream atEnd] " had no effect.
I'm using VisualWorks 7.9.1, under linux and my byteStream is feeded via an UDP Socket.
Any help is welcomed.

Here is the server code:

```
listenOnPort: aPort
| server peerAddr |
self initialize.
server := SocketAccessor newUDPserverAtPort: aPort.
peerAddr := IPSocketAddress hostName:'localhost' port: aPort.
process := 
        [
        [| buf sizeOfBuf |
        buf := String new: 2048.
        sizeOfBuf := server bufferSize.
        sizeOfBuf > 0
            ifTrue: 
                [| dataStream |
                server readWait.
                server receiveFrom: peerAddr buffer: buf.
                dataStream := ReadStream on: buf from: 1 to: sizeOfBuf.
                dataStream reset.
                self receive: dataStream]]
                repeat.]
                fork.
```

Here is the code that parses what is contained in the buffer :

```
parse
^ Array streamContents: [:stream |
    [byteStream atEnd] whileFalse: [stream nextPut: self parsePacket] 
        ]
```

The loop in the parse method, is the problem, i tried the code on a windows xp 32bit and it works fine, but on a linux 32bit it does not, i think it had something to do with the OS UDP networking ?

Comment: Is the socket closed when the loop continues?

Comment: Can you show us more of the code? That may help us better understand the issue and where the problem might be.

Comment: The socket is not closed but the buffer is in the read limit.

Comment: @Dave, i edited the question. The program is meant to parse  open sound control's messages, but i can't post all the code, too big.

Comment: @SolidSnake87 I've downloaded the evaluation copy of VisualWorks. I'll see if I can create a simple case that reproduces this on Linux. I wanted to confirm that `byteStream` from `parse` is the same stream as `dataStream` from `listenOnPort:`, yes?

Answer (score 1):

I found where the problem came from.I was resizing my buffer with a method that parse the size of the OSC BUNDLE, but this method was faulty and it was sending "0" as position to the buffer each time. so each time the loop find the buffer at its initial position and then continue looping, which is logical. thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad you found it. I was unable to pursue this further. The version of VisualWorks I downloaded did not even have the streamContents: method anywhere in the basic image.

Comment: Ah yes you're right, it's not included in the basic image because i wrote it, but as it sounds it only return the stream content this way :    

`streamContents: aBlock

 | stream |
 stream := self new writeStream.
 aBlock value: stream.
 ^stream contents`

Comment: What threw me was when I searched VisualStream's website, streamContents: was used in many examples and forum posts. I thought it was in one of the parcels, but couldn't determine which parcel. :)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "loop continues" ? Clearly it cannot keep reading packets that aren't there. Is it possible that since you put a hardcoded limit on the buffer size that you have a packet at the end of the buffer that is unfinished, thus it fails trying to read the rest of it?